# Triggering javascript function from JSON

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've created an experimental typeface using p5js functions to create the letters. I'm hoping to use a News Feed API with the experimental typeface so that I can pull stories from the API and have them written in my typeface. I'm not exactly sure how to begin with this, as each individual letter requires a different function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function(json) {
  if(json.callbackFlag) {
    eval(data.callbackFunction);
  }
}
```

Here callBackFlag and callBackFunction has to be a property at JSON.